# equivalent indexOf for find value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

im a new blocked because I am learning

i want to remplace a value in array without knowing the position of each word (like tab[0]).

The problem is that you have to find a word, followed by another (search test and remplace test-blabla by another like newblabla

I thought about

```
array = ['test blabla', 'haha hihi']
let index = array.indexOf("test");
if (index !== -1) {
        array[index] = newblabla;
      }
      console.log(index)
```

it return -1 because it's not 'test' its 'test blabla' but I would like that to be replaced 'test blabla' by 'newblabla'

how can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `array.findIndex(s => s.includes("test"))`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find indexOf variable test, which is undefined.

```js
let list = ['test blabla', 'haha hihi']

// here we are doing following things
// 1. We are mapping trough each item of an array
// 2. If item of an array is equals to 'test blabla' then replace it with 'newblabla'
// 3. If item is not equal to 'test blabla', return it without modifing
list = list.map(item => item === 'test blabla' ? 'newblabla' : item);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: sorry its not a variable test its string "test" ;)

Comment: @PierreB, same goes for `newblabla` I assume it is also needs to be string

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple map.

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

// Replace 'b' by something else

const newArr = arr.map(v => (v === 'b' ? 'something else' : v))

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const array = ["test blabla", "haha hihi"];

function searchAndReplace(arr, text) {
  return arr.map((str) => {
    const splitArr = str.split(" ");
    return splitArr[0] === text ? splitArr[1] : str;
  });
}
console.log(searchAndReplace(array, "test"));
```

Comment: This would only work if the string starts with the substring. If the string was something like 'blahblah test', it wouldn't work. Also I think "replace" is misleading (what are you replacing it with?). It's more like "remove if starts with".

Answer (score 0):

There are already two great answers, but based on your feedback I think you are trying to search for strings in an array that contain a given **substring**. To replace items that contain a given substring:

```js
let vals = ['test blabla', 'haha hihi']
// Replace anything in the array that includes the 
// substring we are looking for
let updatedArray = vals.map(v => v.includes('test') ? 'newblabla' : v)
console.log(updatedArray)
```

However, this code would update **any** element that contains the substring 'test'. To replicate what [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is doing, you might want to use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let vals = ['test blabla', 'haha hihi']
// Find index of first element in array with substring 'test'
let index = vals.findIndex(v => v.includes('test'))
if (index !== -1) {
    // Replace element in array with new value
    vals[index] = 'newblabla';
}
console.log(index)
console.log(vals)
```

This second example also has the distinction of updating the existing array, rather than creating and populating a new array.

Comment: best answer. Thanks you man.